# robotframework: define available keywords in a class

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a library implemented as a class within a module:

**MyLib.py**

```
class MyLib(ParentLib):
  def __init__(self):
    #do stuff
    pass

  def keyword(self, arg1):
    robot.api.logger.console('keyword')
```

**ParentLib.py**

```
class ParentLib:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def parent_keyword(self, arg):
    robot.api.logger.console('parent keyword')
```

I can import this library without issue with `Library    MyLib`.  This may seem counter intuitive, but I want to prevent MyLib from providing `Parent Keyword`.  i.e. if a user wants `Parent Keyword`, I want them to be forced to import it manually with `Library    ParentLib`.  Is this possible, or do I need to reorganize the way my library is implemented?

Comment: parent_keyword will be inherited by any ParentLib subclasses. If you want to prevent it, don't subclass it OR override parent_keyword in your subclass

Comment: @Apero I know. I was wondering if robot provides some method of defining what class method are keywords and which aren't, similar to using `__all__` when defining them without a class. (I know that `__all__` is built in python functionality for modules.)

Comment: __alll__ cannot help here. parent_keyword is a method of a class, so if the class is importable its methods are coming along.

Comment: @Apero OK. That's what I figured. Just wondered if robot has some enhanced functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the method `get_keyword_names` to explicitly define which keywords get exposed to the test:

```
class MyLib(ParentLib):
    ...
    def get_keyword_names(self):
        return ["keyword"]
```

The robot framework user guide calls this a [hybrid library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#hybrid-library-api).

Personally I would argue against this. Like you said in the question, this is counter-intuitive.

If you want to keyword libraries to share some common code it would arguably be better to have both `MyLib` and `ParentLib` inherit from a common base, than to have one inherit from the other while hiding the inherited functions. If you're going to hide the functions, why inherit from it?

Comment: if I define `get_keyword_names` without `get_keyword_documentation`, `get_keyword_arguments`, and `run_keyword`, will it still behave properly?  And to answer your question, I have no idea.  I didn't write it.  We're trying to figure out if we can work with it as-is or we need to spend the time to reorganize the library.

Comment: @ewok: The answer to your question is in the user guide: _"When this API is used, Robot Framework uses reflection to find the methods implementing keywords, similarly as with the static API. After getting a reference to the method, it searches for arguments and documentation from it, in the same way as when using the static API. Thus there is no need for special methods for getting arguments and documentation like there is with the dynamic API.
"_